# Connect 4 Java Game Undo Button

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, undo

I am making a Connect 4 Game in java and am a little stuck as to how to make an undo method for it. I know this can be done using either an ArrayList or a Stack but I am not too sure how to implement it. My code for the game and GUI can be seen below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ConnectFourGame {

    private int[][] board;
    //private GameStatus status;;
    private int player, bSize;


    public ConnectFourGame () {
        //status = GameStatus.InProgress;

        Object[] possibilities = {"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
                "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"};

        String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Choose Board Size:", "Sizes", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null, possibilities, "10");

        if(s == null || (s != null && ("".equals(s)))){
            s = "10";
        }

        bSize = Integer.parseInt(s);

        Object[] playerSelect = {"1", "2"};
        String s2 = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Choose Player to Start", "Start", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null, playerSelect, "1");

        if(s2 == null || (s2 != null && ("".equals(s)))){
            s2 = "1";
        }

        player = Integer.parseInt(s2);

        board = new int[bSize][bSize];
        reset();
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return bSize;
    }

    public void reset(){
        for (int r = 0; r < bSize; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize; c++)
                board[r][c] = -1;
    }
    public int selectCol (int pCol) {

        for (int r = bSize - 1; r >= 0; r--)
            if (board[r][pCol] == -1){
                board[r][pCol] = player;
                return r;
            }

        return -1;
    }

    public int nextPlayer() {

        if (player == 1)
            player = 2;
        else
            player = 1;

        return player;
    }

    public int getCurrentPlayer () {
        return player;
    }

    public GameStatus isWinner() {  
        int count = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < bSize; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize - 3; c++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 1) && (board[r][c + 1] == 1) && 
                    (board[r][c + 2] == 1) && (board[r][c + 3] == 1)){
                        return GameStatus.Player1WON;
                }

        for (int r = 0; r < bSize; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize - 3; c++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 2) && (board[r][c + 1] == 2) && 
                    (board[r][c + 2] == 2) && (board[r][c + 3] == 2)){
                        return GameStatus.Player2WON;
    }

        for (int c = 0; c < bSize; c++)
            for (int r = 0; r < (bSize - 3); r++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 1) && (board[r + 1][c] == 1) && 
                    (board[r + 2][c] == 1) && (board[r + 3][c] == 1)){
                        return GameStatus.Player1WON;
    }   
        for (int c = 0; c < bSize; c++)
            for (int r = 0; r < (bSize - 3); r++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 2) && (board[r + 1][c] == 2) && 
                    (board[r + 2][c] == 2) && (board[r + 3][c] == 2)){
                        return GameStatus.Player2WON;
                }

        for (int r = 0; r < bSize - 3; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize - 3; c++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 1) && (board[r+1][c + 1] == 1) && 
                    (board[r+2][c + 2] == 1) && (board[r+3][c + 3] == 1)){
                        return GameStatus.Player1WON;
    }       

        for (int r = bSize - 1; r >= 3; r--)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize - 3; c++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 1) && (board[r-1][c + 1] == 1) && 
                    (board[r-2][c + 2] == 1) && (board[r-3][c + 3] == 1)){
                        return GameStatus.Player1WON;
                }

        for (int r = 0; r < bSize - 3; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize - 3; c++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 2) && (board[r+1][c + 1] == 2) && 
                    (board[r+2][c + 2] == 2) && (board[r+3][c + 3] == 2)){
                        return GameStatus.Player2WON;
                }

        for (int r = bSize - 1; r >= 3; r--)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize - 3; c++)
                if ((board[r][c] == 2) && (board[r-1][c + 1] == 2) && 
                    (board[r-2][c + 2] == 2) && (board[r-3][c + 3] == 2)){
                        return GameStatus.Player2WON;
                }

        for (int r = 0; r < bSize; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < bSize; c++)
                if(board[r][c] != -1)
                    count ++;
                if(count == (bSize)*(bSize))
                    return GameStatus.Cats;



        return GameStatus.InProgress;
    }

    public int [][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void undo(){

    }



}
```

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class ConnectFourPanel extends JPanel{

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel[][] board;
    private JButton[] selection;
    private JPanel top;
    private JPanel bottom;
    private JButton exit;
    private JButton reset;
    private JButton undo;
    private ConnectFourGame game;
    private int boardSize;

    private JMenuItem quitItem;
    private JMenuItem newGameItem;

    public ConnectFourPanel(JMenuItem quitItem, JMenuItem gameItem){
        game = new ConnectFourGame();
        boardSize = game.getSize();
        this.quitItem = quitItem;
        this.newGameItem = gameItem;

        top = new JPanel();
        bottom = new JPanel();  

        reset = new JButton ("Reset");
        top.add(reset);
        undo = new JButton("Undo");
        top.add(undo);
        exit = new JButton ("Exit");
        top.add(exit);

        bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(boardSize+1,boardSize,1,1));  // room for top row

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        exit.addActionListener(listener);
        reset.addActionListener(listener);
        undo.addActionListener(listener);
        quitItem.addActionListener(listener);
        newGameItem.addActionListener(listener);

        selection = new JButton[boardSize];

        for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
            selection[col] = new JButton ("Select");
            selection[col].addActionListener(listener);
            bottom.add(selection[col]);
        }

        board = new JLabel[boardSize][boardSize];

        for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
                board[row][col] = new JLabel("X");
                board[row][col].setForeground(Color.RED);
                bottom.add(board[row][col]);                    
            }
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add (BorderLayout.NORTH,top);
        add (BorderLayout.CENTER,bottom);
    }



    //*****************************************************************
    //  Represents a listener for button push (action) events.
    //*****************************************************************
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //  Updates the counter and label when the button is pushed.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {

            JComponent comp = (JComponent) event.getSource();
            boardSize = game.getSize();

            if ((comp == exit) || (quitItem == comp))
                System.exit(1);

            if(comp == reset || newGameItem == comp){
                bottom.removeAll();
                game = new ConnectFourGame();
                boardSize = game.getSize();
                bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(boardSize + 1,boardSize,1,1));


                ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
                selection = new JButton[boardSize];
                for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
                    selection[col] = new JButton ("Select");
                    selection[col].addActionListener(listener);
                    bottom.add(selection[col]);
                }

                board = new JLabel[boardSize][boardSize];

                for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++) {
                        board[row][col] = new JLabel("X");
                        board[row][col].setForeground(Color.RED);
                        bottom.add(board[row][col]);                    
                    }
                }

                revalidate();
                repaint();

            }

            for(int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++)
                if(comp == selection[col]){
                    int row = game.selectCol(col);
                    if(row != -1){
                        board[row][col].setText("" + game.getCurrentPlayer());
                        game.nextPlayer();
                    }else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Column is full!");

                }

            if (game.isWinner() == GameStatus.Player1WON){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Player1 won!");
            }

            if (game.isWinner() == GameStatus.Player2WON){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Player2 won!");
            }

            if (game.isWinner() == GameStatus.Cats){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cats Game!");
            }




        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried? How do you imagine an ArrayList or a Stack might be used?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you but dropping full code and asking for adding some functionality is not best way to get help here. Short description of how your code works and (even failed) attempt to solve your problem would be better.

Comment: I was figuring if I used a stack I could just push each move into the stack and then when the undo button is hit it would pop it off. Same thing with an ArrayList add each move to the ArrayList and then when undo is hit remove the last entry from the ArrayList, Im just not sure how to implement this with the 2d array and all.

Comment: Pshemo- Sorry, this is my first time posting on here. Basically my code first asks the user the size of the board and which player starts the game (i.e. player 1 or player 2). It then checks when a user selects a column if any of the rows starting at the bottom are open and inserts the player there or tells them the column is full. Im not asking for someone to spit out the code for the undo button for me but I just need some guidance on how this would be done with a 2d Array, Thank you.

Comment: The board is 2d, but each play is uniquely determined by a column, right? So if you just record the column in your stack, you should be able to find the row by using nearly the same logic as is in `selectCol()`.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly looking at your code you could maintain a Stack/List of the board states after each move.

To initalise is easy use: `Stack<int[][]> aStack = new Stack<int[][]>();`

Create a method to copy your board array `getBoardCopy()`

Then for each move

```
aStack.push(getBoardCopy());
```

For undo button create a set board method `setBoard(int[][] aBoard())` then just call this when undoing

```
setBoard(aStack.pop())
```

Comment: Why can't you have a Stack<int[][]>? int[][] is an Object. Anyway, this won't work unless you also make a deep copy of the board when you push it.

Comment: @pburka Fair enough, get mistaken by arrays of primitives, have updated. And the deep copy could be implemented in a method getBoardCopy. Means it would be pretty inefficient though.

Comment: You could be clever about copying the board as only one row changes in each turn. You could share unchanged rows between copies, but I think that significantly increases the difficulty level.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition to use a Stack is correct. You can use a Stack to record which column each player selected. You don't need to record the row or the player, since you can infer both of those things from the current state of the game. When a play occurs, push the column on the stack. When you undo, pop the column from the Stack, and change the top-most piece in that column back to -1.

*Edit: Don't forget to switch users each time you undo, too.*